# Python - get all url from yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I needs to extract data from a yaml file to a dictionary of all url's - below is a sample yaml

```
endpoints:
  app1xxx:
    url:
      - http://xxx/status
      - http://dev-xxx/status
      - http://stg-xxx/status
      - http://tst-xxx/status
  app2yyy:
    url:
      - http://yyy/
      - http://dev-yyy/
      - http://stg-yyy/
      - http://tst-yyy/
```

I tried to get it out something like that :

```
with open(r'file.yml') as file:
    documents = yaml.full_load(file)
    print(documents['endpoints']['app1xxx']['url'])
```

Which of course get url's correctly but from only from 1 application - and any attempts to swap in the second bracket fail - anyone have any advice ?

Comment: `for k, v in documents['endpoints'].items(): print(k, v['url'])`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import yaml

with open(r"file.yml") as file:
    documents = yaml.full_load(file)

urls = []
for app in documents["endpoints"]:
    urls += documents["endpoints"][app]["url"]

print(urls)
```

Comment: So close Mattero - but your code will output several dictionaries for me - and I need one dictionary with everything. But I will look for it soon because your code brings me closer to the solution :) thank you `['http://xxx/status', 'http://dev-xxx/status', 'http://stg-xxx/status', 'http://tst-xxx/status']
['http://yyy/', 'http://dev-yyy/', 'http://stg-yyy/', 'http://tst-yyy/']`

Comment: I will update the code to make one single list with all urls

Comment: Perfect ! :) It works - thank you for helping the newcomer that I am

Comment: No worries, I'm also quite new to programming but your question was clear and minimal enough.